# setup visual studio express for arm

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, arm, panda3d

I'd like to compile panda3d for arm and downloaded the c++ version visual studio express. Sadly the last time I used c++ is about 4 years ago. I googled how to get the project to compile to arm but I only found this:

http://www.ehow.co.uk/how_7675465_add-support-visual-studio-express.html

It looks pretty straightforward but the problem is: I'm using the german version of visual studio and there are no such options. I tried to download the english version but the installer detected my systems language and fell back to german. I searched all menus I could find for proper compiler options but couldn't find anything. Now I wonder: The options can not simply have vanished in the german version. Are you having similar experiences ? Can you give me advice how to setup arm support or where to find the right settings ? Even better, if you're german, too, can you check if you have appropriate menus ?

Thank you for your time

UPDATE:

I'm using windows 7 64bit and have tried visual studio c++ express 2010 and visual studio c++ express 2008. The device I'd like to target will run with a nvidia tegra 3.

UPDATE #2:

I'd like to target a linux distro, most probably ubuntu.

If there's no support for arm in visualstudio I could switch to any other IDE just as well. Actually I only need that one compilation and figured using Visual Studio would be least problematic. If there's another easy alternative I'd appreciate it, if you told me.

Comment: The last version of VS that had an ARM compiler was VS2008.  Not Express, at least Professional (I think).  It targets Windows Mobile.  An operating system that has been put out of business by iApple.  All mobile development tools were removed in VS2010.  This may come back if anybody ever builds an ARM pad for Windows 8.  It would probably target Metro.

Comment: @Hans: Not entirely true: [Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/windows-phone-developer-tools) is obviously a mobile development tool. Doesn't have an ARM compiler, though, as it produces .Net code.

Comment: @lhk: The precise CPU is perhaps the least of your problems, we really want to know the OS. But Tegra3 suggests that you might be considering Windows 8, which brings its own set of issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably unrelated to your German version; my English setup of VS2010 doesn't have that option either. But what precise platform are you targetting? The different Visual Studio versions are tied in with particular Windows CE versions, and compatibility is rather limited.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if OP is aware, but targeting a linux distro doesn't play well with visual studio.
Definitely wrong path.

IMO, using Visual Studio is the best tool for development, with pretty good on-device debugging capabilities, even though ARM support is quite limited, it's still is one of the best tools. But you won't be able to make anything with for a linux distro, it will work only as an advanced text editor.